# Voltage divider circuit for golf cart LED lighting

Tags: led

I have a set of LED lights that I'm installing in my golf cart. The lights take 12v and I'm wiring to two of the 6 8V batteries that I'm running in the cart, so I'm at 16volts. I know this will burn the circuits in the controller so in order to drop down the voltage to 12v, what size resistor would I have to put in place in series, in order to drop the voltage to 12vdc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVUaWE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

See diagram, any help would be great.

Comment: This is not how you want to do this, at all.

Comment: Using a resistor will waste the voltage difference as heat, and tapping two of the batteries will cause them to drain faster than the rest, unbalancing them. Can you tell us more about the LED modules you're using? Clearly they contain internal resistors, if not their own power regulation.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you'll tend to discharge the first two batteries more than the others. Assuming that you charge all the batteries in series and have no battery balancing circuitry in place, you will either reduce your range or else reduce the life of the other batteries. Better to use the full 48V through a regulator was @AndyAka suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best result is to use a buck converter taking in the full 48 volts and outputting 12V. Plenty for golf carts on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/dc-dc-converter-48v-12v): -

[image]

Or, if you wanted to roll your own there's this from LT: -

[image]